# Float data example using Masm

Tags: assembly, floating-point, masm32

Can somebody give me an example how to define a float number or constant in data section of MASM? Or at least some information about it...

Answer (score 6):

I think it's done with

```
.data
   myVar REAL4  1.0f

.code
```

Floating point values are REAL4, REAL8 or REAL10 in Masm.
Expressions (such as #define myConst 1.0f) are done with 
  `myConst EQU 1.0`

These are not specific to any section.

Comment: Is real4 - size of variable?
Thanks, anyway:)