# Compare float sum

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, x87

I'm working on a MASM32 project that performs arithmetic operations. We have to use the coprocessor (8087 instruction set) to use the floating point unit. So, supose my floating point limit is `100.0` then every number must be less than the limit. I'm trying to sum two numbers and then compare the result but it doesn't work.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none
include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\include\user32.inc
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\user32.lib
include c:\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc
.data
    ;Variables de comparación.
    FP_max DD 100
    ;Variables volcadas de la tabla de símbolos.
    _a DD 25
    _b DD 80.0
.code
    start:
         fild _a
         fild _b
         fadd
         fcom FP_max       ;compare ST(0) with the value of the real8_var variable
         fstsw ax          ;copy the Status Word containing the result to AX
         sahf              ;transfer the condition codes to the CPU's flag register
         ja overflow       ;when all flags are 0

        jmp end_program

        overflow:
            print "ERROR: overflow.", 13, 10, 0
            jmp end_program
        end_program:
            invoke ExitProcess, 0
    end start
```

My question is: what i'm doing wrong? How can it fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `fcomi` to set flags directly, as if you had used `fstsw ax` / `sahf`.  (requires ppro I think, i.e. any x86 from the last 20 years.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fild`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/FILD.html) is an integer->FP load.  [`fld`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/FLD.html) is a float load.  (Your assembler magically infers that you want a 32-bit load based by looking at the first directive after the label.  The same instruction can load 64-bit integer or FP.)

`dd` chooses integer or float encoding for the number based on whether there's a decimal point or not in the expression.  (MASM probably has other ways to force FP interpretation, like REAL4.  ([Float data example using Masm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703907/float-data-example-using-masm))

---

You use `fild _b`, but `_b` holds a 32-bit binary floating point value.  Treating that bit-pattern as a 32-bit integer is probably not what you meant to do.

Use  `_b DD 80` instead of `_b DD 80.0`, or use `fld _b` instead of `fild _b`.

You have the reverse problem with `FP_max DD 100`, because you load it from memory with `fcom`.  Make it `REAL4`.

(Or use `ficom`, but note that there's not `ficomi` instruction to compare with an integer and set flags directly.  There's [`fcomi`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/FCOMI:FCOMIP:%20FUCOMI:FUCOMIP.html) (which you should use) that compares floats, and there's `ficom` which is like `fild` + `fcomp` but without needing an extra FP register.  Same idea as `fiadd`).

You should probably be using `faddp` and `fcomip` to also pop the x87 stack, so you don't leave it unbalanced.

See some of the x87 links in the [x87](/questions/tagged/x87) tag wiki.

Comment: But in that case how can I do to define a number like 1,32?

Comment: @TomiSebastiánJuárez.  Oh, I assumed you wanted integers because you were using `fild` instead of the normal `fld`.  You should have said exactly what you wanted in the question. Updated my answer.